# Datetime object produces 'function' object has no attribute 'utc'

Tags: python, date, datetime

I want to create a datetime object with the following code:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, timedelta
print(datetime(year, month, day, tzinfo=timezone.utc))
```

I receive following error:

```
    print(datetime(year, month, day, tzinfo=timezone.utc))
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'utc'
```

I already removed a maybe confusing package import:

```
import datetime as dt
```

If I let the code run in an isolated shell (same environment) or jupyter notebook, it works perfectly fine.

In my code it breaks with the error above.

Other packages I imported are:

```
import sqlite3
import numpy as np
import ast
import glob
import os
import risk_report_creation as rrc
import configparser
import pandas as pd
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
import bbg_api_py as bbg
import warnings
import win32com.client as win32
from tinyflux import TinyFlux, Point, TimeQuery
pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None
from datetime import datetime, timezone, date, timedelta
import schedule
from pretty_html_table import build_table
import pythoncom
from functools import reduce
from time import sleep
from pytz import timezone
import random
import helper_functions_dashboard
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.edge.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.edge.service import Service
```

I'm on python 3.10.2.

Comment: `from pytz import timezone` - what you're interacting with is **not** `datetime.timezone` (which does indeed have [a `utc` attribute](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.timezone.utc)).

Comment: Thank you for helping out. Sometimes the obvious solution is the hardest....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone, date, timedelta
...
from pytz import timezone
```

You're importing `timezone` twice.  The second one replaces the first one.